# Using the AddList Method of Lists Webservice

Tags: list, web-services

I am trying to add a list using the addlist method of Lists webservice. I am not sure how actually I have to get that done.

But I have tried this taking MSDN as reference
1 Added the Lists WebService reference in my empty sharepoint project
2 Added a New Application Page in my solution 
3 Have added this code in my Page_Load function

**Lists listreference = new Lists();
            listreference.Url = "http://'My_Servername'/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
            listreference.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            XmlNode ndList = listreference.AddList("WSList", "Adding List using WS", 100);
            Label1.Text = "List Created";**

4.My solution is successfully deployed but I don't see it in my SPSITE.
5 Am I missing something or Is it not the application page that I should Use or Any other idea??

Any help in making my effort successful would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Hey All, I achieved it.. No Problem Will post If I face any trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue in this line: **XmlNode ndList = listreference.AddList("WSList", "Adding List using WS", 100); Label1.Text = "List Created";**

Following code is working for me:

```
        string listName = "Custom List";
        string description = "List created using SharePoint Web Service";
        // template id for Custom List - 100
        int templateId=100;
        Lists listReference = new Lists();
        listReference.Url = "http://server/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        listReference.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        listReference.AddList(listName, description,templateId);
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I did the same.. But I have passed the values dynamically. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it.. No Problem Will post If I face any trouble